# Using static methods and the value of this in Javascript classes

Tags: javascript, class, oop

I have a Javascript "`GLProgram`" class that is responsible for compiling a WebGL program from two strings.

Compiling a program is not a method called on a program itself so it seems like it should be static.

However, it makes several calls to a `WebGL` object, which is not globally defined.

So that I do not have to pass in this `GL` object to every function, I typically create the object once and then store it in the class.

The class looks like this:

```
class GLProgram {
     constructor () {
       this.gl = gl  
    }
    static makeProgram () {
       // Do stuff with this.gl
    }
}
```

The problem is that if `makeProgram` is static, `this.gl` is not defined.

Are the only solutions for me to make this a non-static function (which would be conceptually wrong) or to pass in a reference to `gl` for ever function that makes a call to the `gl` object?

Here is a more full example of what I want to do:

```
class GLProgram {
     constructor (vert, frag) {
       this.gl = gl
       GLProgram.makeProgram(vert, frag)
    }
    static makeProgram (shader1, shader2) {
       // Do stuff with this.gl
    }
}

   const myProgram = GLProgram('myshader', 'myshader2')
   // But this could also be
   const myProgram2 = GLProgram.makeProgram('myshader', 'myshader2')
   // But this doesn't work because GLProgram can not access this.gl
```

I am aware that `this` is undefined inside of static functions in Javascript, so does that mean I have to pass in a reference to a variable that is defined elsewhere?

Comment: *“Conceptually this should be a static method as it has nothing to do with an instance of this program.”* That’s not correct, as the compiled program needs to be associated with an instance. Problem solved.

Comment: static methods -> static properties - or perhaps a module with module-scoped variables instead of a class

Comment: @Ryan Why does the compiled program need to be associated with an instance?

Comment: That’s the way the WebGL API is designed. Separates the rendering context from the page. (It’s a good design.)

Comment: @Ryan I think with 'nothing to do with an *instance of this program*' OP meant the `class GLProgram`, not the returned `WebGLProgram`. The `makeProgram` function could (should?) very well be static, like a static factory method.

Comment: @le_m: If `gl` is supposed to be the `WebGLRenderingContext`, it can’t be static. (Unless it’s not passed to the constructor as a parameter… which it isn’t here. Not sure if that’s a typo.)

Comment: Startec, can you show a complete example of how you’d like to use `GLProgram`, please?

Comment: Okay, just define a function `makeGLProgram(gl, vert, frag)`. No need for a class.

Comment: You could move those functions into a [module](http://2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html). Passing the gl context each time is actually more readable and standard procedure for such helper functions.Everything else is overly complex.